# EXTJS can't disable Html editor

Tags: extjs

My HTMLEditor in extjs won't be disabled
I tried : 
disabled : true,
it don't want. how to do ???

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: var detailInput = new Ext.form.HtmlEditor({
  width:600,        
  height:180,
                disabled:true,
  id:'detailInput'
 });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`disabled` is not a valid config option for the HTML editor,
try

```
detailInput.setReadOnly( true );
```

instead

Comment: Thanks, added it on render event to be readonly from the start